# run apache and iis on the same machine

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, asp

Im using windows 7 ultimate 64-bit.
I have wampserver installed which installs apache, mysql , and php as all of us know. 
I am now familiar with php. And now I want to learn asp.net. Which needs IIS to run.
I'm just a beginner and I'm not familiar with apache configurations. 
Is there another way of running asp files in apache?How can I run both apache and iis on the same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to run just IIS, which can be used to serve PHP as well.

http://php.iis.net/

Comment: I use phpmyadmin a lot, can I still use tools like this if I run php iis?

Comment: @user37652 - That's a good question; I'm not sure a lot of the functionality of it would apply with IIS. That might be a good separate question.

Answer (score 1):

If you set it up running on different ports it works just fine.
I did run setup like that on windows server 2008 R2,windows 7 pro 64 bit;

2003 and XP pro 32 bit,

Answer (score 1):

If you need all features of IIS and Apache with PHP, you can install both in different ports, or using differents IP Addresses.

You can use WAMP or XAMPP (phpmyadmin is included on the package installer), very easy to install an let you start your apache as service.

If you are looking for IIS to listen port 80 and apache on port 81, also you have to change apache SSL port, because IIS use 443.

If you want to use both on port 80, you can add to your Windows one virtual IP to the Local Conection, under TCP/IP Properties.

You will use your default static IP for IIS and the apache will use the virtual IP.
Then, add some entries on your c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, like:

> iis.local 192.168.x.x 
> apache.local 192.168.x.y

Try to start both services.
If you have any problems starting IIS, take a look at this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732317(WS.10).aspx)
Ask me if you have further questions.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

For Apache there is a mod, http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/ And here is a HowTo: http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx
If you want to run Apache and IIS on the same server, you just need to change Apache's Port (in apache(2).conf or ports.conf or ... / dunno your setup) and install IIS.

Comment: Chillisoft do an asp implementation for Apache too. Or there's ASP2PHP

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried installing both IIS and Wamp on Windows7 yet, but i have installed IIS and Wamp on windows XP. I think it would work on windows7 also.
I had IIS installed. In the Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services window, search for IIS and stopped it.
Installed WAMP and started working on it.
Whenever i needed Wamp, i stopped IIS and started wamp.

Alternatively, we can install IIS and wamp to listen on different ports. But haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the port number of either apache or IIS.  By default they both use the same port (80).  You can change the IIS port by going to IIS manager.

For changing the default port number for apache you need to make few changes to your httpd.conf file.